# Magento quantity field doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

i simply can't find a solution to my problem!
The quantity field worked as it should. After a few months of programming on the whole shop, i wanted to test the quantity field and recognized that it doesn't function.

I only can add one product to the cart although i typed “3” in the quantity field.

I didn’t change anything in product/view.phtml and addtocart.phtml.
Don't know where i have to search for this error.
Maybe someone can give me a tip...

greets max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity field is used in the various product type `prepareForCart` functions. Did you override any of your product classes?

Comment: Hmm, i installed j2t Ajax cart module. Maybe that ruined something.
I wrote in the developers forum but didn't get any answer.
But i noticed, that when i change from my design to the default one, quantity field works. Is that a sign for having the error in a template file ?

Sorry for my bad english, hope you can understand it...

Comment: If you change the design and it works, there's probably a problem with the design. Odds are a template, yes, but it's possible that it's something else. Compare the default template and yours and verify that the quantity input box is rendered in the same way.

Comment: hmmm, just found out that, when i test with a configurable product, i have 2 quantity fields and addtocart buttons! One quantity field is working, the other one not...
Thing i messed up something there...

Comment: Ok, works now. Did take the default view.phtml and replaced it.
But i still don't know where the problem was and may never will know :-)

Comment: @madmax I just have the same problem the box is not adding the quantity entered in the box it just adding default one quantity to the cart...

Answer (score 1):

solved

In my case, the button add to cart had not the original

`onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"`

With this method is not only the product submitted, the quantity is beeing submitted, too. In my on click was

`onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"`

This sent the data via GET and did it always without the quantity. Personaly I do not know, what, why or when the change occured to the view.phtml.

Hope this helps :)