# magento only adds one quantity

Tags: magento

[example](http://www.amishfoods.com/fruits/jam-sampler)

Can't imagine what is causing this- there is a bit of custom template code here but I havn't messed with anything that I'd imagine could effect this as it is.

Any ideas?

BTW This made no difference [quantity field doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958750/magento-quantity-field-doesnt-work), I also just rolled the addtocart.phtml file back to magento base- still failing.

Is there a configuration of some sort I missed, I have inventory turned off.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the "form" element closes before the "qty" input box.

To remedy this problem edit the template files to end the "form" element after the "add to cart" button.

p.s. the reason it is still adding to cart, is because the button runs some JS that takes care of it (but doesn't grab the qty input box)

Comment: Brilliant! I've been distracted with other projects I failed to look at this closely.- As it turns out it was Magento's "Layout" xml file- I had moved that add to cart view out of the form area there.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's because locale config fail. Please use United States as local country and change translations to that folder.

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer. If you look at the accepted answer for this question, you'll see its far from your suggestion. Also - forcing folk to use the US locale isn't a feasible solution.