# Magento : Detail page quantity box is not working

Tags: php, magento

Here is my site detail page 
http://ametrade.dev.icyberking.com/index.php/jp-3004242.html

The cart item quantity box is not adding more than one item to the cart no matter whatever quantity is added written to the box i have search through google but did't find any working solution to my problem i also found below link for the same problem but i have nothing that i can do wtih this.. please help

[Magento quantity field doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958750/magento-quantity-field-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the HTML layout the input field "qty" is not inside the "add to cart" form. Therefore, the data entered into that field is not even posted (detectable with firebug). You should check the page layout and make sure the field is within the form tags.