# Magento quantity field doesn't work when product have custom option

Tags: php, magento

I have a strange problem with qty box in Magento. Whatever number i type in qty box, only 1 item gets transferred to the cart.

I have found, that if i remove all product options (eg. color/size etc.) it works fine and whatever qty i type gets transferred to the cart, but with product option it does not work.

I have checked this [Magento quantity field doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958750/magento-quantity-field-doesnt-work) without luck.

It is a simple product and i didn't change anything in addtocart.phtml

Any suggestoions?

Comment: Have you tried to look in the code file you mentioned and see if you can figure out what's going on?

Comment: Yes, i have checked that file and i see only 2 if statements, "isSaleable" and "isGrouped". Am i missing something?

Comment: Where is that file? addtocart.phtml

Comment: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: Ah, that just generates the html. You're going to want to look at the code that processes the `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` event for the button. Seems like a lot to dive into.. sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @user1857818 I doubt some javascript error. Do you use firebug to check JS errors?